# How can I queue a custom email when an order is placed?

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I am sent an email when an order is placed, but there is speed issue.
Can you advise me how to add a custom email to the queue when an order is placed?

```
try {
        $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
        $mail->setToName($email);
        $mail->setToEmail($email);
        $mail->setBody($html);
        $mail->setSubject("Automated Bundle Purchase: Coupon Code");
        $mail->setFromEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'));
        $mail->setFromName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));
        $mail->setType('html');
        $mail->send();
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When the message is queued, the email data is saved in the Magento database where it will be later fetched and an email message will be reconstructed from the data and sent. The data is stored in two new tables, one for the email data and one for the recipients:

```
<email_queue>
    <table>core_email_queue</table>
</email_queue>
<email_recipients>
    <table>core_email_queue_recipients</table>
</email_recipients>
```

**When and how is the queue cleared ?**

```
<core_email_queue_send_all>
    <schedule><cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
    <run><model>core/email_queue::send</model></run>
</core_email_queue_send_all>
<core_email_queue_clean_up>
    <schedule><cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
    <run><model>core/email_queue::cleanQueue</model></run>
</core_email_queue_clean_up>
```

That means the `send()` function on the queue will be called every minute and the clean up once per day at midnight `00:00`.

So you can reference you to this one :

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
    /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
    $emailQueue = $this->getQueue();
    $emailQueue->setMessageBody($text);
    $emailQueue->setMessageParameters(array(
            'subject'           => $subject,
            'return_path_email' => $returnPathEmail,
            'is_plain'          => $this->isPlain(),
            'from_email'        => $this->getSenderEmail(),
            'from_name'         => $this->getSenderName(),
            'reply_to'          => $this->getMail()->getReplyTo(),
            'return_to'         => $this->getMail()->getReturnPath(),
        ))
        ->addRecipients($emails, $names, Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_TO)
        ->addRecipients($this->_bccEmails, array(), Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_BCC);
    $emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();

    return true;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.aschroder.com/2015/01/sending-emails-by-queue-in-magento-1-9-1/)

**EDIT:**
Try to add this before `send()`:

```
/** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
        $emailQueue = Mage::getModel('core/email_queue');
        $emailQueue->setEntityId($this->getId())
            ->setEntityType(self::ENTITY)
            ->setEventType(self::EMAIL_EVENT_NAME_NEW_ORDER)
            ->setIsForceCheck(!$forceMode);

        $mail->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

Comment: This all is accepted. But how we can add custom email on that queue table.
You sent me mechanism. But how we can add an entry of mail in that queue table?

Comment: You create your custom module `custom email` based on `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` => `sendTransactional`, `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue` I don't see what is complicated. Look my Edit